# Imagem não se alinham

Tags: css, css3

Tenho o seguinte relatório que estou fazendo para fins de aprendizagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
ul.ulHorizontal {   
    height: 50px;
}
ul.ulHorizontal li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul class=ulHorizontal id=listaRegistros style="background-color:#CCC">
      <li style="text-align:left; width:200px;">Leve</li><!--
    --><li style="text-align:left; width:200px;">Produto 1</li><!--
    --><li style="text-align:right; width:100px;">120.33</li><!--
    --><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;">1</li><!--
    --><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;">Correios</li><!--
    --><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;"><a href="?produtos&editar&idProdutos=1"><img src="imgs/editar.png" height="30px"  title="Editar Produto"/></a></li><!--
    --><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;"><a href="?produtos&bloquear&idProdutos=1" onclick="return verifica('Deseja Bloquear este produto');" ><img src="imgs/bloquear.png" height="30px"  title="Bloquear Produto" /></a></li><!--
    --><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;"><a href="?produtos&excluir&idProdutos=1" onclick="return verifica('Deseja Excluir este produto?');" ><img src="imgs/excluir.png" height="30px"  title="Excluir Produto"/></a></li>
    </ul>
```

uma **ul** (que representa cada linha) é como acima.

O **problema** é que não consigo **centralizar** as **figurinhas** no **centro** **vertical**.

Percebam que os **textos** estão ok.

O que devo fazer?

**EDITADO**:

**Li** com a **imagem**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Li** com os **textos**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Perceba** a **diferença** nos **tamanhos** das **caixas** das **li's**

**Edição:**

```js
function verifica(msg) {

 return confirm(msg);

};
```

```css
/* CSS Document */
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
*, 
*:before, 
*:after, 
*:active, 
*:hover {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
    border:0;
    outline: none; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: content-box; /*Comprimir(diminuir) as medidas do elemento para não aumentá-lo quando adicinar margin e padding*/
}
ul {
 list-style: none;

}ul.topo{
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
ul.topo li {
 text-align: center;
}
ul.ulHorizontal { 
 height: 50px;
}
ul.ulHorizontal li {
 display: inline-block;
 line-height: 50px;
}
ul.ulHorizontal li img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
a, a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
button, 
input[type=button], 
input[type=submit], 
input[type=reset] {
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #CCCCCC; 
}
button:hover, 
input[type=button]:hover, 
input[type=submit]:hover, 
input[type=reset]:hover {
 background-color: #DCDCDC; 
 border: 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2) solid;
}
button:active, 
input[type=button]:active, 
input[type=submit]:active, 
input[type=reset]:active {
 background-color: #FFFFFF; 
}
/************   CORES   **************/
.bgcCinza100 {
 background-color: #CCC;
}
.bgcCinza25 {
 background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
.bgcPreto100 {
 background-color: #000;
}
.bgcBranco100 {
 background-color: #FFF;
}
.bgcVermelho100 {
 background-color: #F00; 
}
.bgAzulCiano {
 background-color: #007EAE;
}
/************   CORES   **************/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 
 <head>
  <title>MVC PDO CRUD</title>
     <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="imgs/favicon.png"/>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 
 <body>

  <ul class="ulHorizontal topo">
     <li style="width:200px">CATEGORIA</li><!--
  --><li style="width:200px">NOME</li><!--
  --><li style="width:100px">PREÇO</li><!--
  --><li style="width:100px">FRETE</li><!--
  --><li style="width:100px">TRANSPORTE</li><!--
  --><li style="width:100px">EDITAR</li><!--
  --><li style="width:100px">BLOQUEIO</li><!--
  --><li style="width:100px">EXCLUIR</li>
  </ul>
  
  <ul class=ulHorizontal id=listaRegistros style="background-color:#CCC">
      <li style="text-align:left; width:200px;">Leve</li><!--
      --><li style="text-align:left; width:200px;">Produto 1</li><!--
      --><li style="text-align:right; width:100px;">120.33</li><!--
      --><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;">1</li><!--
      --><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;">Correios</li><!--
      --><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;"><a href="?produtos&editar&idProdutos=1"><img src="imgs/editar.png" height="30px"  title="Editar Produto"/></a></li><!--
      --><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;"><a href="?produtos&bloquear&idProdutos=1" onclick="return verifica('Deseja Bloquear este produto');" ><img src="imgs/bloquear.png" height="30px"  title="Bloquear Produto" /></a></li><!--
      --><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;"><a href="?produtos&excluir&idProdutos=1" onclick="return verifica('Deseja Excluir este produto?');" ><img src="imgs/excluir.png" height="30px"  title="Excluir Produto"/></a></li>
  </ul>
  
 </body>
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente basta colocar `vertical-align: middle` nas `img`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
ul.ulHorizontal {   
    height: 50px;
}
ul.ulHorizontal li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
}
ul.ulHorizontal li img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul class=ulHorizontal id=listaRegistros style="background-color:#CCC">
   <li style="text-align:left; width:200px;">Leve</li><!--
--><li style="text-align:left; width:200px;">Produto 1</li><!--
--><li style="text-align:right; width:100px;">120.33</li><!--
--><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;">1</li><!--
--><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;">Correios</li><!--
--><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;"><a href="?produtos&editar&idProdutos=1"><img src="https://placecage.com/30/30" height="30px"  title="Editar Produto"/></a></li><!--
--><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;"><a href="?produtos&bloquear&idProdutos=1" onclick="return verifica('Deseja Bloquear este produto');" ><img src="https://placecage.com/30/30" height="30px"  title="Bloquear Produto" /></a></li><!--
--><li style="text-align:center; width:100px;"><a href="?produtos&excluir&idProdutos=1" onclick="return verifica('Deseja Excluir este produto?');" ><img src="https://placecage.com/30/30" height="30px"  title="Excluir Produto"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok. Funcionou. Obrigado! Mas me tira uma dúvida: Como é que funcionou se você não estilizou a tag <a>?  Não seria o caso de ter que colocar nela 100% da li? Senão, porquê? Porque a img flutuou na li se ele está dentro de uma tag <a> que não foi estilizada? Entende as minhas dúvidas?

Comment: @CarlosRocha entendo sim, e alinhou pq o A já está centralizado na LI devido ao line-height de 50px, que é o mesmo height da UL :D essa imagem vai te ajudar a entender http://prntscr.com/nt6ud9

Comment: Sim. Mas sabe o que eu percebi aqui? Que a li que é 50px, ond tem os links e as imagens. ela está se reduzindo ao tamanho das imagens. Vou adicionar uma figura no final da pergunta mostrando.

Comment: @CarlosRocha estranho pq aqui a LI tem a mesma altura do UL devido ao line-height, http://prntscr.com/nt708u ja a imagem estava alinhada na "base-line" do A, mas com o vertical-align a imagem centralizou verticalmente no A já que os dois são inline

Comment: hum viu as duas imagens que postei?

Comment: @CarlosRocha vi mas aqui ficou assim https://imgur.com/ZJliTGO não sei se tem algum CSS a mais ai... de qq forma, esse comportamento não vai influenciar no seu layout pelo que parece, aparentemente ficou tudo alinhadinho mesmo ai

Comment: então, coloquei no final da pergunta uma verdão total da pagina com todos os arquivos envolvidos

Comment: @CarlosRocha testei aqui e aparentemente aqui não fica assim... https://imgur.com/OKzpsIR tb não entendi pq a preocupação já que o alinhamento esta preciso e o layout me parece ok. http://prntscr.com/nt74r3

Comment: A preocupação é só com o aprendizado mesmo. Encontrar o porque disso para que quando ocorrer novamente mais tarde eu saber do que se trata.

Comment: @CarlosRocha ta certo, o comportamento seria como eu falei mesmo, só não entendi pq aqui renderiza de um direito e ai de outro, talvez possa ser a versão do browser ou algo assim

Comment: Bingo: testei no FF e está coreto. Parece que só no Chrome dá esse erro. Será que tem algum hack para corrigir isso?

Comment: Notei que no Chrome e no Edge existe um tal de offset alpem das margins no inspector que esta mdificando o tamanho da li ao tamanho do objeto img

Comment: @CarlosRocha então é isso mesmo, ta vendo como até essas coisas tão simples podem depender do estilo do user-agent do browser... pelo menos nesse caso não atrapalho o resultado final do layout... Não precisa se preocupar em "corrigir" isso, não nesse caso.

Comment: beleza, Entendido. Mais uma vez, obrigado!